# getter and setter issue

Tags: java, getter-setter, jform

I have this problem where I set the value for some variables from a jForm to a class where I store the variables. Set the values, Ok, get the values, Ok.
But when I go to a different jForm and call the getters it returns empty values.
I don't know what is wrong with my code and would really apreciate if someone could help me on this one.

The code is pretty straigth-forward

```
public class Variables
{
    private int Var1;
    private int Var2;
    private double Var3;
    private int Var4;

    public int getVar1() {
        return capacidad;
    }

    public void setVar1(int Var1) {
        this.Var1 = Var1;
    }

    public int getVar2() {
        return Var2;
    }

    public void setVar2(int Var2) {
        this.Var2 = Var2;
    }

    public double getVar3() {
        return Var3;
    }

    public void setVar3(double Var3) {
        this.Var3 = Var3;
    }

    public int getVar4() {
        return Var4;
    }

    public void setVar4(int Var4) {
        this.Var4 = Var4;
    }
}
```

For example, I set all the values calling the functions from a jForm like this:

```
variables.setVar1(value1);
variables.setVar2(value2);
variables.setVar3(value3);
variables.setVar4(value4);
```

Then I try to get the values from a different jForm and they are all 0s

(edit)

I have already tried to call them from the same jForm where I set them and works just fine

(editedit)

jForm1 code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int value1;
        int value2;
        double value3;
        int value4;
        try
        {
            value1 = (int) 1Spinner.getValue();
            value2 = (int) 2Spinner.getValue();
            value3 = (int) 3Spinner.getValue();
            value4 = (int) 4Spinner.getValue();
            if(value1>0)
            {
                variables.setVar1(value1);
                variables.setVar2(value2;
                variables.setVar3(value3);
                variables.setVar4(value4);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.orintln("Error");
        }

    }
```

jForm2 code:

```
int value1;
int value2;
int value3;
int value4;

Variables variables = new Variables();
value1 = variables.getVar1();
//and so on, all of them return empty
```

Comment: Can you show us the code from both of your jForms?

Comment: Please also provide your code initializing the jForm. I think those jForm may not have the same Variables reference

Comment: Just added the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code in jForm2 creates a new instance of the `variables` variable. So any instance members are going to be uninitialized.

```
Variables variables = new Variables();
```

if you want it to have the same values from jForm1, you need to provide a way for jForm2 to get them from jForm1, like so:

```
// in jForm1
private static Variables variables = new Variables();
public static getVariables() {
    return variables;
}

// in jForm2
Variables variables = jForm1.getVariables();
```

OR you can declare your `Variables` instance members to be static like so:

```
public class Variables {
    private static int Var1;
    private static int Var2;
    private static double Var3;
    private static int Var4;
```